# Disabling user switching when admin locks screen

Tags: security, gnome, xorg, x11

Well, pretty much what the subject says, is it possible to forbid users from using the "Switch User" feature when the screen is locked by an administrator?

I'm not sure if user switching is a GNOME or X feature.

Answer (score 1):

I personally would recommend not running a GUI as root; it's a quick trip to always running as root (administrator), and that way lie viruses, spyware, and rootkits. They do exist for Linux. (That way also lies accidentally entering 'rm -rf /' on a terminal. As a normal user, it errors out. As root, it erases your hard drive. I learned this the hard way `;D`)

According to cube3x3 at [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=111132) forum discussion:

To disable "switch user" in terminal:

$ gconf-editor

When gconf-editor opens, go to 'desktop -> gnome -> lockdown'
In that select 'disable_user_switching' .

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm not running as root per-se, just as a user that has "admin" privileges, that is, a "sudoer". I'm not trying to disable user switching completely (although that's an option if I can't do what I'm trying to, so thanks for the pointer).

Comment: gconf-editor changes per-user settings, not global ones. It should only disable user switching for that user.